# What does "would have done" mean when it's not in subjunctive mood?

Tags: tense

[Source](https://novelonlinefull.com/chapter/lunar_chronicles/chapter_38)

> Levana **would have known** right away who you are, although I doubt
>   anyone else has figured it out yet, and Levana will try to keep it
>   hidden as long as she can.

There is no "if", so it's not in subjunctive mood right?

Does it mean "Levana probably has already known ..."?

Comment: Bear this in mind: there is **an implied if clause** which only you can imagine or figure out **since only you can see what precedes the text you posted**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of sentencecs are possible without if clauses.They are not in  subjuntive mood even with if clauses.They are called **conditional perfect**.

**I desire that she come**

**He suggested that she go**
In the above sentences the verbs are in the subjunctive mood.

> **You should have attended the meeting**( but you did not attend.It was very fruitful))

You might have seen me at the market( I think that you saw me)

You must have seen me( my strong belief is that you saw me )

> **Leena would have known right away who you are**( I believe that Leena has known you who you are)

Here is the link which helps you know what subjunctive mood is:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood

Answer (score 0):

**An implied *if* clause:**

Levana would have known right away who you are [**if she had seen you**] although I doubt anyone else has figured it out yet, and Levana will try to keep it hidden as long as she can.

**The if clause can be implied.** You can see that by adding "if she had seen you" in parenthesis, the meaning immediately becomes clear.

This kind of usage is common in conversations. The people talking do not always spell out an if clause if they know the context.

Comment: @Lambie.Do we consider that leena has  has seen him or not?

Comment: @Englishmonger There is an implied if clause. It can be seeing, speaking to, gawking at.....I really can't say for sure, as I have explained.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about "subjunctives". *Would* is a modal, and like all modals has two  sets of meanings: *deontic* meanings, about objective things - possibility, willingness, obligation; and *epistemic* meanings, about the speaker's knowledge.

Here the sense is epistemic. I would paraphrase the first clause as

> **I deduce that** *or* **I am sure that** Levana knew right away who you are.

There is no *if*, implied or otherwise.